# How have foreach loop with this simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am parsing xml using simplexml_load_string like this :

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

        echo '{'.
            '"Date":"'.$xml->Date[0].'",'.
            '"Description":"'.$xml->ShipTos->ShipTo->ShippingGroups->ShippingGroup->OrderItems->OrderItem->Description[0].'",'. 
            '"Track":"'.$xml->Shipments->Shipment->Track[0].'"'.
            '}';
```

This works ok but if a node appears in the xml multiple times it only grabs it once.  Can someone please help me understand how I would write a foreach loop specifically for the Description node?

Comment: simple_xml tends to make things, IMO harder to process, have you tried DOMDocument?  $dates = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Date");  foreach( $dates as $date ) { } ?

Comment: no, thanks jeremy i will investigate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only referring to one instance of each `SimpleXMLObject`.
For example `$xml->Date[0]` refers to the first occurence of a Date object only. To print all Date objects you need to
loop through them

```
foreach( $xml->Date as $date ){
   print (string)$date;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`children`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) function:

```
foreach( $xml->children('Date') as $date ){
   print (string)$date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$datebuffer;
$count = 0;
foreach($xml->Date as $date){
   $count++;
   datebuffer .= "Date:".$count ." ".$date; 
}
```

and so on...